# open modal window component from controller

Tags: angular

I have created a component called AlertModal which should overlay a modal window as follows:

Template:

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Controller:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-alertmodal',
  templateUrl: './alertmodal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alertmodal.component.css']
})
export class AlertmodalComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And I use this in another component MyComponent in the template:

```
<app-alertmodal #alert>this is a test</app-alertmodal>
```

and in the controller of MyComponent:

```
@ViewChild('alert') alertWindow; 

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { /* some stuff */ }

open(this.alertWindow);  // This is run when I click a button

open(content) {
  this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
    this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
  }, (reason) => {
    this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
  });
}

private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
  if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
    return 'by pressing ESC';
  } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
    return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
  } else {
    return `with: ${reason}`;
  }
}
```

And portions of app.module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AlertmodalComponent,
    // And more of my components
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    NgbDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: false } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  entryComponents: [AlertmodalComponent],
  providers: [GetInterfaceListService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule, NgbDropdownModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
// import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AlertmodalComponent } from './shared/alerts/alertmodal/alertmodal.component';
```

The problem is that why I run the code that should show the alertwindow, it errors:

> compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'NgbModal' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

If I remove the import from my app module, I get error:

> mycomponent.html:29 ERROR Error: No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

---

UPDATE:

If I comment out the

```
<app-alertmodal #alert>this is a test</app-alertmodal>
```

then the 'No component factory found' error disappears, and a grayed washed out overlay appears on my screen (but no window).

Seems like something is just wired up wrong / I misunderstand something.  I assume the above line has to be in my view in order to pass the HTML content 'this is a test' to my alert window.

Comment: are you using `NG2BS3` modal?

Comment: You have not imported ViewChild. import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

Comment: Post app.module also please

Comment: I am using ngBootstrap (so Bootstrap 4 with Angular 2)

Comment: I have imported viewchild in MyComponent.

Comment: I posted app.module (most) above

Comment: You need to include entryComponents option :)

Comment: I have ' entryComponents: [AlertmodalComponent],' in the app.module but get the error above.

Comment: I saw that you have to forRoot()s is that expected?

Comment: I thought I needed forRoot on those 3 - and all seems to work except for the modal window.  (Should only 1 item have forRoot ?)